# add click event when hitting enter key on wizard form

Tags: jquery, html, wizard

I have a wizard form that's essentially one large form that has multiple buttons.

One small UX issue I have is if you hit the enter key, nothing will happen, which may be off putting to some users.

I'm lost as to how I can accomplish this and have it activate the correct action.

Comment: On key press, check for the enter key, if enter key, do action.

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922266/cross-browser-handling-the-enter-key-pressing-using-javascript

Comment: Are all your inputs in the same form? Does it have an `action` attribute? Does it have a `submit` event? Can we see some of your code? Can you reproduce this issue with a minimal version of your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the keypress function

```
     $(document).keypress(function(e) {
      if(e.which == 13) {
       // Code 
      }
    });
```

Comment: That's great, I found another SO article that helped further, thanks.